# Graph API --> liking the post of a fan of the page I manage using the page account token, not working

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

```
    $accounts = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=" . $access_token); 
    $accounts_obj = json_decode($accounts);
    $page_access_token = $accounts_obj->data[0]->access_token;

    $attachment = array( 
                        'access_token' => $page_access_token
                    );

    $likes_response = $facebook->api("/".$object_id."/likes", 'post', $attachment);
```

trying to like the post of a fan of the page I manage.
whether or not I use the page_access_token or the regular access_token, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) Permissions error thrown in ...../htdocs/facebook-php-sdk-master/src/base_facebook.php on line 1332

... the regular access token is a 2 months (60 days) access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem seems to be that a fan page doesn't have full access to its own fans' pages and feeds. As a page I can't like my fans' posts anymore than any other non-friend, and it's also like that in normal browser navigation.